# PR_Write after hooking

Tags: c, post, https, hook, mozilla

So i recently hooked PR_Write in Mozilla and was able to log results( all of the connection literally ) to a log file, there's however one problem, i was assuming that after hooking PR_Write, i would be able to capture HTTPS data but when i log in to an HTTPS server, it doesn't capture the unencrypted POST data, i tried using localhost and making a fake POST and it captures the localhost post considering it's not encrypted. Is the point of hooking PR_Write not to capture all kinds of data?

This is the prototype of the PR_Write that i'm using and the variable:

```
typedef int (*Custom_Write)(PVOID, LPVOID, INT);
Custom_Write c_write=NULL;
```

[PR_Write definition by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSPR/Reference/PR_Write)

and in the detour function, i call the original PR_Write by getting the address which is stored in `c_write` using GetProcAddress. Below is how it's called:

```
// detour function
int detour_pr_write(int fd, LPVOID buf, int bytes)
{
    // ... code for virtual protect
    int retaddr=c_write(fd, buf, bytes);
    // file functions
    fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), strlen(buf), fileHandle);
    // ... code for virtual protect
    return retaddr;    // go to original function
}
```

The logging and other stuff works fine but when it comes down to writing encrypted POST data, it fails. It ends up writing gibberish.

Comment: Sure - it's got strlen() in it.  Bound to be wrong.

Comment: I wonder why the hooked call has that 'int bytes' parameter?  I'm sure it must be there for some reason.....

Comment: the definition of PR_Write has those three parameters as referred to here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSPR/Reference/PR_Write

Comment: Umm... OK.  Now what about the arguments to fwrite()?   Can you match them up with the parameters to PR_write, at all?

Comment: i'm assuming PR_Write uses char so i'm writing sizeof(char) and getting the length..it works with localhost unencrypted data..

Comment: 'and getting the length' - why are you doing that? Think again...

Comment: 'PR_Write' uses a void pointer and........

Comment: that's the reason i'm converting the void pointer to a (const char*)..

Comment: OK, let's try from the other end.  What do you think that strlen() does?

Comment: .. and what do you think that  'int bytes' is?

Comment: I gave up and wrote an answer..

Comment: I get the same question, is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1):

'write(buf, sizeof(char), strlen(buf), fileHandle);' - the strlen() call is both inappropriate and unnecessary.  Not only does it not work reliably with void pointers that may, or may not, point at null-terminated char arrays, it is redundant because you already know how many bytes/chars to write - it's passed in as the 'int bytes' parameter.

Get rid of the strlen() call;

```
fwrite(buf, 1,bytes, fileHandle);
```

strlen() is not required and cannot work reliably with binary data that may contain embedded nulls.

With network code, strlen() is a disaster 99.9% of the time.

Comment: damn, yes, how could i not have seen that haha lemme try this code